# PouchDB Local-to-Remote replication goes into "paused" with no record replicated

Tags: local-storage, pouchdb

I am trying to build a sample Web app with PouchDB (local storage) and CouchDB on the back-end.

I wrote a simple function to initiate the replication:

```
function sync (db, remotedb) {
        // force initial replication
        db.replicate.to(remotedb).on('complete', function(info) {
            // then two-way, continuous, retriable sync
            // I also tried: PouchDB.sync( db, remotedb, { 
            db.sync(remotedb, {
                live: true,
                retry: true 
            })
            .on('change',   handlers.change)
            .on('paused',   handlers.paused)
            .on('active',   handlers.active)
            .on('denied',   handlers.denied)
            .on('complete', handlers.complete)
            .on('uptodate', handlers.uptodate)
            .on('error',    handlers.error)
        })
    }
```

Communication with the server works:

```
Oct 20 13:31:48 xyz couchdb[1934]: [info] [<0.123.0>] 88.185.58.128 - - GET /temperatures/_local/oTKz4LpqfD7uDhJTD6JbXQ%3D%3D? 304
Oct 20 13:31:48 ebpml2 couchdb[1934]: [info] [<0.123.0>] 88.185.58.128 - - GET /temperatures/_changes?style=all_docs&feed=longpoll&heartbeat=10000&since=0&limit=100
```

The initial replicate call returns an "info" structure with zero records to replicate.

When I check the local storage, I can see all the records:

```
_pouch_temperatures!Ã¿by-sequenceÃ¿0000000000000001   {"sensorId":"sensor1","temp":"20.2","ts":1508501121994,"_id":"temp-1508501121990","_rev":"1-b42aab0dee1742b7b8a5119c38613ca9"}
```

When the server doesn't have the local database/collection it creates it, so I am certain they communicate properly and the problem is that the local database believes it has zero records to replicate.

So I am not quite sure what I could be doing wrong (I also tried without a forced replication and the same behavior is observed). I checked a number of code samples too and they don't seem to differ from my code. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Hmm you could try to log/output all documents in your db **just before** starting the replication, just to make sure they're actually in there ;) e.g. using `allDocs`: https://pouchdb.com/api.html#batch_fetch

Comment: it returns "null", which would be consistent with the observed behavior. 
I do make a query right after that (getById) and it returns the correct document.

Comment: Maybe you're not handing over the parameter `db` correctly. You could check again before calling the `sync` function...

Comment: I tried a number of things including querying a document prior to starting the replication

`db.get('setpoint').then( function (docs) { db.replicate.to(remotedb).on('complete', function(info) { ...`
                        
and I get the `setpoint` document back correctly, but immediately after that the info response is "zero document to replicate". It looks like there is something else at play here.

Comment: Strange one... Maybe you could create a fiddle/[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or upload your complete code somewhere, so someone can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Here is the sample code: https://codepen.io/sam-pattern/pen/yzWRaJ
At the moment the replication is not working because the browser is blocking it (requires https). I'll try to set it up over https, but that's not the issue on my side, since I am running both over HTTP. The PouchDB console can be found here: http://107.170.225.99:5984/_utils/database.html?temperatures

Comment: @Phonolog I got CouchDB running on HTTPS, and of course the replication is now working :-) in CodePen, that gives me a starting point. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The problem was the way I was creating an instance of my PouchDB adapter, the odd thing though that everything else was working except replication! Thank you again.